# Linkage error when compiling C file and Assembly file

Tags: c, assembly

I have .s (x86 assembly at&t syntax) file, .h (header) file with struct defenition and functions decleration which are implemented in the assembly file, and main.c file with function call (from the .s file).

when trying to compile it all together, i get the following error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
/home/user/workspace/Assembly/main.c:7: undefined reference to `pstrlen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

pstring.h:

```
typedef struct {
    char len;
    char str[255];
    } Pstring;


char pstrlen(Pstring* pstr);
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pstring.h"

int main() {
    Pstring a;
    a.len = 4;
    printf("Length: %d", pstrlen(&a));
    return 0;
}
```

pstring.s:

```
    .file   "pstring.s"
    .section    .rodata
invalid_input:  .string "invalid input!\n"


    .text
    .type   pstrlen,    @function
pstrlen:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %ebp, %esp

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   # assign given pstring ptr address to eax
    movzbl  (%eax), %ecx    # set ecx with the value of the first byte (length) of the address at eax
    movl    %ecx, %eax      # set return value as the value at ecx

    ret

    .type   pstrcpy,    @function
```

makefile:

```
a.out: main.o pstring.o
    gcc -m32 -g -o a.out main.o pstring.o

main.o: main.c pstring.h
    gcc -m32 -g -c -o main.o main.c

pstring.o: pstring.s
    gcc -m32 -g -c -o pstring.o pstring.s   

clean:
    rm -f *.o a.out
```

Thank you.

Comment: You mention C and Assembly, but why tag C++ too?

Comment: I can't see the "pstring.h" target in your makefile. Is that the complete makefile you use? main.o depends on the pstring.h, so where is it?

Comment: it is the complete makefile, where should i include the .h file?

Comment: doesn't the `make` invocation cause errors like `No rule to make target "pstring.h", needed by "main.o".  Stop`?

Comment: The only error I get when executing make is the error written in post.

Comment: Please try to substitute string `main.o: main.c pstring.h` just to `main.o:` and post a result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by declaring pstrlen as global as follows:

```
    .text
    .globl  pstrlen
    .type   pstrlen,    @function
pstrlen:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %ebp, %esp

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   # assign given pstring ptr address to eax
    movzbl  (%eax), %ecx    # set ecx with the value of the first byte (length) of the     address at eax
    movl    %ecx, %eax      # set return value as the value at ecx

    ret
```